# What are fish shell command-line ui patterns?

Tags: fish

I want to construct an ui similar to what git have `git <command> [<param1> ...]`. What I came up with so far is:

```
function git -d "Description"
    switch $argv[1]
        case branch
            git_branch $argv[2]
        case reset
            git_reset
    end
end

function git_branch -d "Description for branch"
    do_something $argv[1]
end

function git_reset -d "Description for reset"
    do_something_else
end
```

It works, but there are couple problems:
1. Fish doesn't pick up available commands for auto-completion;
2. If I run `git` with no arguments it wouldn't print out list of command, neither it would pick up descriptions for them.

It appears to me that what I'm doing is not the "right" way to construct command-line utilities with fish. So, what is the right way?

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement Git?!

Comment: @Biffen of course not, I have a set of scripts to automate my workflow and I want all of them to be accessible through the same namespace, so I can have different scripts for the different projects to have the same simple names like `project_1 sync` and so on.

Comment: Hmm, I also have a git function, and `git <tab>` autocompletes the git subcommands. I don't have any special git completions.

Comment: @glennjackman fish has git autocompletion bundled with it (see https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/completions/git.fish ), but my question is unrelated to the git itself.

Comment: I understand that. I was just relating that you and I are doing basically the same thing with different results. Wait, I see the difference ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problems occur because you don't have a default branch if your switch statement, so you never call out to the actual git command. Try:

```
function git -d "Description"
    switch $argv[1]
        case branch
            git_branch $argv[2]
        case reset
            git_reset
        case '*'
            command git $argv
    end
end
```

To protect against the case where zero arguments are provided, I do this:

```
function git -d "Description"
    set -q argv[1]
    and switch $argv[1]
        case branch
            git_branch $argv[2]
            return
        case reset
            git_reset
            return
    end
    command git $argv
end
```